# python - finding multiple strings in multiple strings

Tags: python

I can use this to determine whether or not any of a set of multiple strings exist in another string,

```
bar = 'this is a test string'
if any(s in bar for s in ('this', 'test', 'bob')):
    print("found")
```

but I'm not sure how to check if any of a set of multiple strings occur **in any of many** strings.  It seems like this would work.  Syntactically it does not fail, but it doesn't print me out anything either:

```
a = 'test string'
b = 'I am a cat'
c = 'Washington'
if any(s in (a,b,c) for s in ('this', 'test', 'cat')):
    print("found")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to iterate through the tuple of test strings:

```
a = 'test string'
b = 'I am a cat'
c = 'Washington'
if any(s in test for test in (a,b,c) for s in ('this', 'test', 'cat')):
    print("found")
```

Answer (score 2):

At this point it's probably worth compiling a regular expression of the substrings you're looking for and then just apply a single check using that... This means that you're only scanning each string once - not potentially three times (or however many substrings you're looking for) and keeps the `any` check at a single level of comprehension.

```
import re

has_substring = re.compile('this|test|cat').search
if any(has_substring(text) for text in (a,b,c)):
    # do something
```

Note you can modify the expression to only search for whole words, eg:

```
has_word = re.compile(r'\b(this|test|cat)\b').search
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking time to answer a question I already accepted an answer on.  This is a great idea, and in my case of checking 50 strings against 5 strings, it should actually make things faster and more efficient, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
a = 'test string'
b = 'I am a cat'
c = 'Washington'

l = [a, b, c]

tests = ('this', 'test', 'cat')

if any(any(i in b for b in l) for i in tests):
    print("found")
```

Comment: This is actually really clean, and my real dataset is much larger - this might make things a lot easier to read in the end.  Thank you!

Comment: @BrianPowell glad I could help!